# MongoDB Compass - searching by ID

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

Using MongoDB Compass (last version) I have created the following document under a collection:

```
_id
6412f4e691b08789204bc17a
name
"James"
```

After that, if I create a different collection that will be linked with the former collection by the ID, for example using this code:

```
{
  "title": "xxxx",
  "text": "...",
  "date": ISODate("2022-03-15T10:00:00Z"),
  "author": ObjectId("6412f4e691b08789204bc17a"),
  "tags": [
    {"tag": "COVID-19"},
    {"tag": "Vacunas"}
  ]
}
```

I am not able to create that document for that collection, I always get the error "Insert not permitted while document contains errors."

Why is that? since the ID is the same from the document created in the other collection.

In order to be able to create this document, I have to remove the "author" and "date" lines, meaning that there are issues in both lines.

What could be happening?
thanks in advance

I have tried changing the syntax but the issue persists

Comment: Its working on my side. Do you have any validations setup on the collection?

Comment: Also, I am using mongo shell (mongosh.exe) and not mongodb compass. I issued: `test> db.stack.insertOne({ "title": "xxxx", "text": "...", "date": ISODate("2022-03-15T10:00:00Z"), "author": ObjectId("6412f4e691b08789204bc17a"), "tags": [ { "tag": "COVID-19" }, { "tag": "Vacunas" }] })`

Comment: Hi,Yes in shell it works, but it should work also in compass, right? I need to manage to do it there

Comment: Can you send a picture of how you're doing it in compass